# hello, about the source of 10.11 in《APUE》 about signal

Tags: c, linux

i'm read the 《APUE》,and i find the example of 10.11 can't create the right answer.
the 10.11 file is:

```
static void sig_quit( int );

int main( void )
{
        sigset_t newmask, oldmask, pendmask;

        if ( signal( SIGQUIT, sig_quit ) == SIG_ERR )
                err_sys( "can't catch SIGQUIT" );

        sigemptyset( &newmask );
        sigaddset( &newmask, SIGQUIT );

        /* block SIGQUIT and save current signal mask */
        if ( sigprocmask( SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask ) < 0 )
                err_sys( "SIG_BLOCK error" );

        sleep( 5 );     /* SIGQUIT here will remain pending */

        if ( sigpending( &pendmask ) < 0 )
                err_sys( "sigpending error" );
        if ( sigismember( &pendmask, SIGQUIT ) )
                printf( "\nSIGQUIT pengding\n" );

        /* reset signal mask which unblocks SIGQUIT */
        if ( sigprocmask( SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL ) > 0 )
                err_sys( "SIG_SETMASK error" );
        printf( "SIGQUIT unblocked\n" );

        sleep( 5 );     /* SIGQUIT here will terminate with core file */

        exit( 0 );
}

static void sig_quit( int signo )
{
        printf( "caught SIGQUIT\n" );

        if ( signal( SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL ) == SIG_ERR )
                err_sys( "can't reset SIG_QUIT" );

        return ;
}
```

when i execute ./a.out and key in  ctrl+c in less 5 seconds, the program will be end right away.
if it work in the right way in 《APUE》, it will print:

```
^\
SIGQUIT pending
caught SIGQUIT
SIGQUIT unblocked
^\Quit(coredump)
```

i'm a new one learn the signal.please me how to understand why?
i can use gdb when the other errors appeared. but the signal, so please, thank you
i work it in  ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CTRL+C` generates `SIGINT`, `CTRL-\` generates `SIGQUIT`. See [Termination Signals - the GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html)